# Reading data from locked table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, locking

I have two processes

1) First is loading a big amount of data (rows) to table `A` and make table  locked

2) Second is trying to read table `A`.

I can't use `NOLOCK` hint. Also we don't have replication server.

Is there another way to improve second process?

Comment: How are you loading the data?

Comment: Why not able to use `NOLOCK?`

Comment: @Diado : by Spring - > similar way like bulk insert ( SQL Server ) works

Comment: @gotqn - > company rules :(. No hints - > WHY ? I don't know ...

Comment: Why don't you first bulk insert to a temp table and then move data from temp table to table A. That should cut down the locking time substantially.

Comment: you could enable snapshot isolation.

Answer (score 1):

My two suggestions would be following. You can use both or one for some meaningful cut down in locking time.

1. Load to a staging table/temp table and perform all data cleaning/transformation here. From this table load to actual `tableA`
2. Batch the load process and put each batch in transaction. So instead of loading 1 million records to your table, load 10K records 100 times.
   To do this you need to read only write ( and read maybe) only few lines and keep an external index/counter on process to know how many lines have been written to the tableA.

Since you are using bulk insert I'd suggest you to look and use the FIRSTROW and LASTROW properties as given in **[documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**

You'd need to wrap the BULK INSERT into a dynamic SQL with a WHILE Loop like below

```
DECLARE @bulk_cmd varchar(1000); 
DECLARE @NUM int =1, @STEP int=3; 
--create table abc(a varchar(100),b varchar(100),c varchar(100));
WHILE (@NUM<100)
BEGIN

SET @bulk_cmd = 'BULK INSERT abc  
FROM ''D:\samplefile.txt''   
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR ='','', FIRSTROW = '+CAST(@NUM as varchar(100))+',LASTROW='+ CAST(@STEP-1+@NUM as varchar(100))+')';  

EXEC(@bulk_cmd);  
IF @@ROWCOUNT < @STEP
BEGIN
SET @NUM=@NUM+1000
END
SET @NUM=@NUM+@STEP

print @bulk_cmd
END

--truncate table abc
```

you can do both where you load everything to a staged table and move data from staging to actual table in batches

Comment: Could you show, please, how is it possible to implement `Batch the load process and put each batch in transaction` through code?

Comment: @StepUp explained with example query

Comment: Could you tell, please, where are here batches?

Answer (score 0):

Your P1 can load the data into a separate table with its schema being identical to your main table. No one except this process touches it, so no locks.

The second process, P2 is reading rows that are currently in your main table. No locks, no waits.

When P1 finishes its load, its destination table is switched into a partition of the main table. The switch only affects metadata, and happens very quickly.

Unless P2 is actually trying to read rows which are loaded by P1, everything should work fine. That, and you will be able to manage partition restrictions like the ones described [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69930/alter-table-switching-from-regular-table-to-partitioned-table-fails). Also, partitioned tables might require Enterprise Edition of SQL Server which can be costly (this has been alleviated in 2016 SP1).

This approach, or anything similar will work if the data is clean and schema is identical. I assumed this because you are already loading your data directly into your destination table, and apparently isn't going to cleanse it.